# How to prevent Uglify un-escaping "</script" in strings?

Tags: javascript, gulp, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify

I've got code like this:

```
var string = '<script src="' + src + '">\x3c/script>';
```

I've used `\x3c` instead of `<` to avoid having a closing script tag (which would end the script early if used as an inline script in a web browser, breaking everything).

But uglify unfortunately converts it back into a `<` character, breaking my page.

It looks like Uglify has [an option](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#beautifier-options) called `inline-scripts` intended to fix this, but there are no docs on using this option with the API (I'm using it via [gulp-uglify](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify) so I need to be able to pass this option in an options object, not via the CLI).

How do I do it? None of the following work:

- `{'inline-script': true}`
- `{inlineScript: true}`
- `{beautify: {inlineScript: true}}`
- `{beautify: {'inline-script': true}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, however, the answer given is not correct. You need to use the `output` object in uglifyjs.

```
.pipe(uglify({
    output: {
        'inline_script': true
    }
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be specified with underscore, as this:

```
options: {{beautify: {'inline_script': true}}}
```